# How to get post data variables after submition a form in magento

Tags: magento

How do I get data of post variables ? Like if I post form with post method then I can get itt with $_REQUEST or with $_POST. How I can do this in mgento ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get all variables using `$this->getRequest()->getParams();`. This will return all variables. For any particular name like `id` you can use `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');` without the "s". Hope this will help.

Answer (score 27):

You can read the values with

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('field_name');
```

The code above will get you values from `GET` and `POST`.
But if you want to check if something was sent specifically through `POST` you can get it like this.

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost('field_name');
```

You can even specify a default value.

```
$somevar = $this->getRequest()->getParam('some_var', 7);
```

this means that if `$_POST['some_var']` is not set, the variable `$somevar` will have the value `7`.

Comment: @downvter what's the problem with my answer?

Comment: @Mariuswhy do you care about downvoters i really say yiu are doing a great job. I don't know magento i know little android. WHerever i stuck due to magento code. I always found you. Thanks for being here. I know downvoter wont reply.

Comment: @Shubham. I don't care that much. I was thinking that maybe I did something wrong and I need to improve my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Return array with params post/get

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Return value by field name

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('field');
```

Also can gat with default value, and check/use in script logic

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('field', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention for everyone looking into this thread..

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams('value_here');
```

is just wrong...
The only available method to retrieve a special param with or without default value is without s

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('param','defaultValue');
```

All other comments are just wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this way:

replace 'ship-note' with your custom field.

```
$delivery_instruction_note = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ship-note');
```